# React state adds 1 but subtracts 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a function to like/unlike posts and add or subtract 1 from the likes total. Something isn't right as the addition works correctly (adds 1) but it subtracts 2 for some reason. I am not sure if it's to do with the state update delay.

```
const Post = (props: PostProps) => {
  const {
    post: {
      content,
      author,
      postedDate,
      likes,
      comments,
      shares,
      isLiked,
      isBookmarked,
    },
  } = props;

  const [isPostBookmarked, setIsPostBookmarked] = useState(isBookmarked);
  const [isPostLiked, setIsPostLiked] = useState(isLiked);
  const [likesCount, setLikesCount] = useState(likes);

  const handlePostLikeClick = () => {
    setIsPostLiked((prevIsLikedState) => {
      setLikesCount((prevLikesCountState) => {
        return prevIsLikedState
          ? prevLikesCountState - 1
          : prevLikesCountState + 1;
      });

      return !prevIsLikedState;
    });

    return (
      <IconButton
        icon={Heart}
        label={likesCount}
        filled={isPostLiked}
        onClick={handlePostLikeClick}
      />
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting two different state updates in same function which leads to some fuzzy issues,

Can you try changing you `handlePostLikeClick` function to the one mentioned below??

```
  const handlePostLikeClick = () => {
    setLikesCount((prevLikesCountState) => {
      return isPostLiked ? prevLikesCountState - 1 : prevLikesCountState + 1;
    });
    setIsPostLiked((prevIsLikedState) => {
      return !prevIsLikedState;
    });
  };
```

You can use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-leftpad-42i35r?file=/src/App.js:666-923) code sandbox for reference

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @sumanth seems quite right, but it seems something missing. In the given answer, using same onClick function `handlePostLikeClick`, 2 states are going to be updated. But it should only be used to update `isPostLiked`. Because `likesCount` should be updated only if any state changes detected for `isPostLiked` state. Therefore, it is essential to use `use effect` as follows.

```
  const [isPostLiked, setIsPostLiked] = useState(false);
  const [likesCount, setLikesCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLikesCount((current) => (isPostLiked ? current + 1 : current - 1));
  }, [isPostLiked]);

  const handlePostLikeClick = () => {
    setIsPostLiked((prevIsLikedState) => !prevIsLikedState);
  };
```

**Explantion**

Initial state for `likesCount` used as 1, because during initial rendering `use effect` will be triggered and update `likesCount` to 0 (since `isPostLiked` initial state is `false`). Additionally, you can see `likesCount` increases its count only if `isPostLiked` is `true`.

But with @sumaneth answer, `likesCount` increases if `isPostLiked` is false.

```
isPostLiked ? prevLikesCountState - 1 : prevLikesCountState + 1;
```

Therefore, it's not tracking current change of `isPostLiked` state, but it's using its previous state to do the update on `likesCount`.

Therefore, you defenitely, need to use `use effect` to keep track on the current change of `isPostLiked` state and do the update on `likesCount`.

Comment: Yeah but the `isPostLiked` changes on post load as well because it may possibly change from false to true on init when a loaded post has been liked before. I don't feel setting a default value to 1 just because it's then reset to 0 is right.